# How to write a function to find the longest common subsequence using dynamic programming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, longest-substring

To be clear I am looking for the subsequence itself and not the length. I have written this function which works the majority of the time but in some cases it doesn't work. I have to write this recursively without any loops or imports. I used a memoise function to be more efficient but didn't include it here.

This function works when s1 = "abcde" and s2 = "qbxxd" (which correctly returns "bd") but it doesn't work for when s1 = "Look at me, I can fly!" and s2 = "Look at that, it's a fly" which should return "Look at , a fly" but I get instead "Look at a fly". For whatever reason the comma and the space is ignored. I've tried s1 = "ab, cde" and s2 = "qbxx, d" which correctly returns "b, d".

```
def lcs(s1, s2):
"""y5tgr"""
i = len(s1)
j = len(s2)
if i == 0 or j == 0:
    return ""
if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
    return lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1]) + s1[i-1]
else:
    return max(lcs(s1[:-1], s2), lcs(s1, s2[:-1]))
```

I have a feeling the problem is with the last line and the max function. I've seen solutions with for and while loops but not without.

Answer (score 2):

There's only a slight change to fix your code (you're right the problem was in max).

Just change max so it finds the *string of max length* using it's key function.

```
def lcs(s1, s2):
    """y5tgr"""
    i = len(s1)
    j = len(s2)
    if i == 0 or j == 0:
        return ""
    if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
        return lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1]) + s1[i-1]
    else:
        # Find max based upon the string length
        return max(lcs(s1[:-1], s2), lcs(s1, s2[:-1]), key=len)
```

However, this is very slow without memoization

**Code with Memoization** (to improve performance)

[Memoization Decorator Reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize)

```
import functools

def memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer

@memoize
def lcs(s1, s2):
    """y5tgr"""
    i = len(s1)
    j = len(s2)
    if i == 0 or j == 0:
        return ""
    if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
        return lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1]) + s1[i-1]
    else:
        return max(lcs(s1[:-1], s2), lcs(s1, s2[:-1]), key=len)
```

**Test**

```
s1 = "Look at me, I can fly!"
s2 = "Look at that, it's a fly"
print(lcs(s1, s2))
```

**Output**

```
Look at ,  a fly
```

Answer (score 0):

For strings, `max` takes the string which *lexicographically* goes last:

```py
>>> max("a", "b")
'b'
>>> max("aaaaa", "b")
'b'
>>>
```

Certainly not what you need; you seem to look for the *longer* of the two.
You don't need a loop, just a comparison:

```py
lsc1 = lcs(s1[:-1], s2)
lcs2 = lcs(s1, s2[:-1])
return lcs1 if len(lcs1) > len(lcs2) else lcs2
```

Comment: Thank you, however when I do this this exceeds the maximum recursion depth limit so I get the error message: "builtins.RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".